# limit and continuity notation meaning δ=min(30ϵ,1)

Tags: real-analysis

what is the

> δ=min(30ϵ,1)

mean in real analysis continuity and limit?
what does the min notation choose from that scope?
I want to know what is the notation mean and δ values also

Comment: It means you pick the minimum between $30\varepsilon$ and $1$ as the value of $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

It means $\delta=30\epsilon$ if $\epsilon\lt1/30$ and $\delta=1$ otherwise.